# Google Nearby Connections - Timed Advertising

Tags: java, google-nearby-connections

I am using google Nearby connections to create a P2P network using the Star strategy and I was wondering if it is possible to set the advertising device to stop advertising after a 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a thread, with a timer. If the timer reaches 0, and you are advertising, then call the corresponding `stopAdvertising()` method.

Besides this, keep in mind that the user should be aware when the device is advertising via an icon or a special screen. This is stated in [this video](https://youtu.be/hultDpBS22s?t=203) (they talk about nearby messages, rather than connections, but the best practices still apply).

What I mean, is that it would be odd to have the user waiting for 5 minutes in the same screen while advertising. Most likely he quits before the 5 minute window has passed, at which point you must also stop advertising. If you think in your application the user might stay in the advertising screen for over 5 minutes, then use the counter in a thread.